# volume not getting mounted in nginx container

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

I have the below compose file which starts 2 containers

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - node:node
    volumes_from:
      - node

  node:
    container_name: node
    build: .
    env_file: .env

    command: npm run package
```

The dockerfile for node

```
FROM node:6.0

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8000
```

`docker-compose up` doesnt seem to mount the node volumes into nginx. I require the volume to serve the static files from node

```
location / {
    #The location setting lets you configure how nginx responds to requests for resources within the server.
    proxy_pass http://node:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpeg)$ {
  root /usr/src/app/public;
  expires 30d;
}
```

the volume is present in node

```
avernus@avernus-VirtualBox:~$ docker exec -it node bash
root@127bddea4e31:/usr/src/app# ls                                                                                                            
Dockerfile  docker-compose.override.yml  migrations    postgres-test  shared         webpack.config.js
Makefile    docker-compose.prod.yml  node_modules  public         socketcluster  webpack.production.config.js
client      docker-compose.yml       package.json  server         test
```

But Nginx doesnt seem to have the volumes

```
avernus@avernus-VirtualBox:~$ docker exec -it nginx bash
root@47ca17fac4b3:/# cd /usr/src/app                                                                                                          
bash: cd: /usr/src/app: No such file or directory
```

Is there something else i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node part of your docker-compose.yml doesn't declare any volumes - how should docker know which part of your node image should be shared! Try adding something like this to the node service in your compose yaml:

```
volumes:
  - /usr/src/app
```

Comment: You're right .. thank you so much :). I cant seem to get my head around how these volumes work