# Mount 'dist' folder from UI containers to an NGINX container using a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, volume

I see a great many threads asking similar questions that are answered using docker commands, not using a Dockerfile definition.  I have '***n***' number of UI containers running '***node***', that I need to point another container running '***nginx***' to their built 'dist' folders:

```
FROM nginx:1.13.7   
VOLUME ["factory-ui"]
RUN mkdir -p factory-ui
COPY /apps/factory-ui/dist /factory-ui
```

Where `/apps/factory-ui/dist` is the npm rendered folder on a running container named `factory-ui` and I need to mount this folder on the nginx container as an endpoint at it's root, ergo `https://clueless.com/factory-ui`. I do not see how I tell the nginx container what container to mount the volume from for each dist folder path within each UI container.  I think I have overcomplicated this, but I am not seeing the answer. In my Dockerfile for `factory-ui` I have the following (abbr.):

```
FROM node:8.9.3
.
.
.
RUN npm install && \
    npm run build
VOLUME [ "/apps/factory-ui/dist" ]
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do. Rather than present the way you're trying to solve the problem, can you clarify the behavior you want to achieve?

As an aside: Bind mounting which is what it sounds like you're trying to do is a runtime activity. So, it'd have nothing to do with your Dockerfile.

ETA: I *think* [this is what you're trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127318/volume-not-getting-mounted-in-nginx-container?rq=1)?

Comment: I am attempting to use the ''dist" folders created when running "npm run build" in other containers I am building/running within the nginx container I am trying to create.  These are all in separate repos as well so there is some challenge in that as well.  I guess I need to to understand how to declare a volume in a Dockerfile for each container that I want to globally share the dist folder volume for use as endpoints by nginx.